# I am working on Sending push notification to android devices from C# Web app

Tags: c#, android, azure, push-notification

I am Creating Application to send push notifications to Android devices using `firebase` and azure notification hub.

How to store `RegistrationID` using `Push.RegisterAsync` In my Code ...
Here `RegistrationId` is generated from `firebaseinstanceID Refresh Token which is every time new So how Can I handle that`id` for sending notifications to registered devices?

```
var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;

var templates = new JObject();
templates["genericMessage"] = new JObject
{
    { "body", templateBodyFCM }
};

var client = new MobileServiceClient(HalalApps.App.MobileServiceUrl);
var push = client.GetPush();
await push.RegisterAsync(refreshedToken, templates);
```